# Call stored procedure on Microsoft SQL Server using ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, go

I have a stored procedure let the name be "vijaystoredprocedure" , if it is some query in mssql then i will query in Go like

```
l_query_str = fmt.Sprintf(`select * from Users where Fname='%s'`, l_firstanme)

row, err := DBC.Query(l_query_str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Prepare failed:", err.Error())
    }

    _, rows, r_err := DBScan_fn(row)

    if r_err != nil {
        fmt.Println("no data found err")
        return
    }
```

now since i have to get values from a stored procedure...can some one suggest how to acheive this in go

Comment: This looks like MySQL not MSSQL.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.4487.0

Comment: Then why tag MySQL?

Comment: What package are you using to work with your DB server? This is a) crucial for us to try asking your question; b) it may contain ready-made means to work with stored procedures.

Comment: An immediate suggestion is to try using prepared statement containing `execute vijaystoredprocedure` then actually execute the statement passing the necessary parameters in. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188332.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @kostix , actually it solved my problem upto some extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `github.com/alexbrainman/odbc` driver,
Example of executing stored procedure:

```
    proc := "exec Dbo.vijaystoredprocedure ?, ?, ?, ?" //(Number of parameters)
    parms := []interface{}{"parm1","parm2","parm3","parm4"}// Parameters if needed

    if Stmt, err := DBC.Prepare(proc); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    } else {
        defer Stmt.Close()
        if result, err := Stmt.Exec(parms...); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
    }
```

Example of stored function:

```
proc := "SELECT * From Dbo.[vijaystoredprocedure](?,?)" //(Number of parameters)
parms := []interface{}{"parm1","parm2"}// Parameters if needed
row, err := DBC.Query(proc, parms...)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Prepare failed:", err.Error())
}

_, rows, r_err := DBScan_fn(row)

if r_err != nil {
    fmt.Println("no data found err")
    return
}
```